# PL/SQL DBMS OUTPUT in Procedure Not Displaying

Tags: sql, plsql

I created this procedure to validate a login. The DBMS OUTPUT in the first IF statement outputs fine, but the DBMS OUTPUT in the ELSE statement doesn't display anything when I enter invalid info; I'm not sure why?

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE member_ck_sp
    (p_username IN VARCHAR2,
     p_password IN VARCHAR2)
     IS
     p_check VARCHAR2(10):= 'INVALID';
     fullname VARCHAR2(20);
    CURSOR member_cur IS
    SELECT username, firstname, lastname, cookie, password
    FROM bb_shopper
    WHERE username = p_username
        AND password = p_password;
     BEGIN
      FOR rec_cur IN member_cur LOOP
          IF p_username = rec_cur.username AND p_password = rec_cur.password THEN
              fullname := rec_cur.firstname || ' ' || rec_cur.lastname;
              DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Name: ' || fullname || ' Cookie: ' || rec_cur.cookie);
              DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('LOGGED IN');
            ELSE
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('INVALID');
          END IF;
      END LOOP;
      END member_ck_sp;
      
      
      
    BEGIN
        member_ck_sp('rat55', 'kile');
    END;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cursor For Loop how to print message when not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52920043/cursor-for-loop-how-to-print-message-when-not-found)

Comment: The condition `p_username = rec_cur.username AND p_password = rec_cur.password` is always true.  The cursor is only selecting rows from the table where the username and password match.  Your `IF` statement then makes another check that they match (which will always be true), hence the `ELSE` block will never be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have used the below SQL query for the cursor and when you give invalid input so the `for loop` that iterates cursor values will be `not found` and it will skip iterating the loop and hence your program will end without informing that the Input was invalid.
You can use a `flag variable` that can inform you whether the for loop ran or not.

```
SELECT username, firstname, lastname, cookie, password
FROM bb_shopper
WHERE username = p_username
    AND password = p_password;
```

---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE member_ck_sp
(p_username IN VARCHAR2,
 p_password IN VARCHAR2)
 IS
 p_check VARCHAR2(10):= 'INVALID';
 fullname VARCHAR2(20);
 data_present BOOLEAN := FALSE;
CURSOR member_cur IS
SELECT username, firstname, lastname, cookie, password
FROM bb_shopper
WHERE username = p_username
    AND password = p_password;
 BEGIN
  FOR rec_cur IN member_cur LOOP
      IF p_username = rec_cur.username AND p_password = rec_cur.password THEN
          fullname := rec_cur.firstname || ' ' || rec_cur.lastname;
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Name: ' || fullname || ' Cookie: ' || rec_cur.cookie);
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('LOGGED IN');
          data_present := TRUE;
      END IF;
  END LOOP;
  --Checking Invalid input 
  IF NOT data_present 
  THEN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('INVALID');
  END IF;
  END member_ck_sp;
```